# How can I use web service from Silverlight app?

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf

I am trying to get data form a web service inside a silverlight app.  Unfortunately the silverlight app (Bing map app) just hangs when trying to connect.

I use the same code in a console app and it works just fine.

Is there anything special I need to do in silverlight to get it to work?  I don't get any exceptions - it just hangs.

I based my service and client code off of this example
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication

Problems and Questions:

**1. Why can't I set breakpoints in my sliverlight code?**

**2. How can I successfully call WCF service from a silverlight app?** (links to SIMPLE working examples would be great - all the ones I seem to find seem to be quite advanced (RIA, Duplex, etc)  Many of these also show xml and other non C# "code" - frankly I don't know what those do and how they relate to the projects, code and services.

(Clearly I am quite ignorant about WCF and silverlight)

As per request for code:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ILGSMapServer
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<double> GetLatitudes();
}    


public class TreeWorkClient
{ 
ChannelFactory<ILGSMapServer> httpServer;        
public ILGSMapServer httpProxy;        

public TreeWorkClient()
{
    httpServer = new ChannelFactory<ILGSMapServer>(new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8000/GetLatitudes"));
    httpProxy = httpServer.CreateChannel();
}        

public List<TreeWorkItem> GetLocations()
{
    List<double> lats = httpProxy.GetLatitudes();


    //...  do stuff in code
    return ret;
}
```

}

Comment: Please actually _show_ the code you use to call the service.

Comment: Pretty sure you need AsyncPattern = true on your OperationContract for  silverlight

Comment: @MerickOWA - I have no idea what that is.  Where/what is that?  How do I set it?

Comment: @Tim I posted an answer that shows an example of what you'd need to change

Answer (score 2):

I agree with John Saunders - it would be easier to answer this if you published the client code.

However as a guess, a common problem with calling services from Silverlight applications is the restriction Silverlight puts on cross domain calls.

In summary, if your service is at a different domain from the site-of-origin of the Silverlight application, you need to create a client access policy file at the service location.

See this for details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: I have no idea what this answer means.  All this is on a local machine - I am just trying to test right now.  I know nothing about configuration of the "Service"/"Server" - I just created the service programmatically.

Comment: Ah, sorry Tim. I didn't realise it was all local. I presume the service is at the same location as where the silverlight application is served from (localhost:8000)?

Comment: There are two different solutions/exes.  One is an app that serves the WCF - and is on localhost:8000.  the other is a bing map silverlight app.  http://localhost:56888/BingTestPage.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

Given your example code you should be seeing the

> System.InvalidOperationException: The contract 'ILGSMapServer'
>   contains synchronous operations, which are not supported in
>   Silverlight. Split the operations into "Begin" and "End" parts and set
>   the AsyncPattern property on the OperationContractAttribute to 'true'.
>   Note that you do not have to make the same change on the server.

You'd need to change your service contract to the following

```
  [ServiceContract]
  public interface ILGSMapServer {

    [OperationContract( AsyncPattern = true )]
    IAsyncResult BeginGetLatitudes( AsyncCallback callback, object context );
    List<double> EndGetLatitudes( IAsyncResult result );
    }
```

This also means you'll need to do something completely different in your GetLocations() function as this function will return before the results from the Web have been returned.

Try taking a look at the examples [here](http://storypodders.com/blog/blog/manual-wcf-proxies-in-silverlight/).

Other options involve using the "Add Service Reference" rather than manually defining it in code.

Comment: Thanks. I see no exceptions at all.  I tried following that link/content.  I am lost.  I got as far as changing the service contract in the C# code but after that I am totally lost.  I think I just have to go back to C++ programming...

Comment: @Tim WCF is a large complex but very flexible beast.  Silverlight enforces that you do everything asynchronously.  You're not allowed to block the UI while WCF is out retrieving data.  I would suggest learning this pattern and understanding what its doing.

Comment: @MerrickOWA - thanks - I have no problem with threading or asynchronous behavior - the issue for me is that .NET, c#, the tools, WCF, Silverlight, heavy use of xml, etc are ALL new to me.  The web sites I have been looking at and reading seem to assume a lot of knowledge and experience with the very things I am struggling with.  I really appreciate the help.  I am close to getting the asynch working with my code...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to have this attribute on WCF service for SL to consume it:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
```

As for debugging - you can debug Silverlight, try using IE for that, its most natural browser for SL debugging (sadly).

Once you start debugging it will be more clear whats wrong when you catch cross domain exception or some other.